# How to split string having multiple JSON data string

Tags: c#, json, .net

I'm trying to split a string having two valid JSON strings in a file. My data looks something like this

```
{
    "notes_report": {
        "Version": "1.0",
        "SubscriberId": 123456,
        "ItemId": 98745632,
        "Allocations": [
            {
                "AllocatedAdjustmentId": "98745632",
                "AllocatedAdjustmentNumber": "DN00412345698",
                "Date": "2022-10-11T07:29:00.000Z",
                "AmountPaid": 3.0,
                "Balance": 2.0,
                "OriginalBalance": -5.0
            }
        ],
        "ReferenceId": "CN00432165498",
        "NoteType": 1,
        "AccountNumber": "ACCQ1023654789",
        "Amount": -10.0,
        "RemainingBalance": -7.0,
        "Currency": "USD",
        "CreatedDate": "2022-10-11T07:29:00.000Z"
    },
    "BusinessUnitId": 255,
    "EventNotificationType": 2139,
    "EventDate": "2022-10-13T16:57:33.873Z"
}
{
    "notes_report": {
        "Version": "1.0",
        "SubscriberId": 741085,
        "ItemId": 32014587,
        "Allocations": [
            {
                "AllocatedAdjustmentId": "98741023",
                "AllocatedAdjustmentNumber": "CN00432165498",
                "Date": "2022-10-11T07:29:00.000Z",
                "AmountPaid": -3.0,
                "Balance": 10.0,
                "OriginalBalance": 10.0
            }
        ],
        "ReferenceId": "DN00400146452",
        "NoteType": 2,
        "AccountNumber": "ACCQ1023654789",
        "Amount": 5.0,
        "RemainingBalance": 5.0,
        "Currency": "USD",
        "CreatedDate": "2022-10-11T08:50:00.000Z"
    },
    "BusinessUnitId": 255,
    "EventNotificationType": 2139,
    "EventDate": "2022-10-13T16:57:33.896Z"
}
```

My requirement is to separate the two JSON and get individual JSON string value.
Can anyone help me with this? The schema doesn't have any class as such. It's just a string format file with some attributes. Also the file will have at max 2 JSONs strings not more than that.
But whatever attributes we have here, I always expect those in the file.

Comment: The following may be helpful: [JSON Utils](https://jsonutils.com/), [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=net-6.0), NuGet package [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm)

Comment: I would add `[` and `]` around the text, and parse it as a JSON array of objects using any of the parsers above.

Comment: Do you want _strings_ or _objects_?

Comment: @DStanley strings

Comment: How do you receive you json? is it in this format `[{},{}]`?

Comment: @Ibrahim It's the same content how I've mentioned in the question

Comment: @BiswajitMaharana So basically you are appending json to a file and then you want to retrieve individual json from it. I updated my answer to achieve this

Comment: @BiswajitMaharana its good to give feedback on the answers. Also don't forget to accept an answer or atleast upvote a working solutions as apprecation for the effort made.

Comment: @Ibrahim I've added a comment on your answer

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**
This method tracks for opening and closing root curly brackets to extract json strings from the file. It should work using the format you shown in the question.

```csharp
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Read file containing json and split to lines
        var text = File.ReadAllText("json.txt");
        var lines = text.Split(Environment.NewLine);

        // variables for tracking and storing json
        var isJson = false;
        var counter = 0;
        var content = string.Empty;
        var jsonList = new List<string>();

        // loop throuch each line to find for root
        // opening and closing curly brackets
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            // store each line
            content += line + Environment.NewLine;

            if (line.Contains("{"))
            {
                counter++;

                // detones a start of a json
                if (!isJson)
                    isJson = true;
            }
            
            if (line.Contains("}"))
            {
                counter--;

                // detones an end of a json
                if (counter == 0)
                {
                    jsonList.Add(content.Trim()); // add json

                    // reset tracking
                    isJson = false;
                    content = string.Empty;
                }
            }
        }

        // Loop through json strings
        foreach (var json in jsonList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(json);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Method 2:** This method uses both `string.Replace` and `string.Split`to extract json strings from the file by separating each json using `delimiter` (where one json ends and the next begins)

```csharp
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = File.ReadAllText("json.txt");

        // inject curly brackets so that we can split without loosing
        // one on each side
        text = text.Replace("}\r\n{", "}}\r\n{{");

        var jsonArr = text.Split("}\r\n{");

        // print 1st json
        Console.WriteLine("This the 1st json");
        Console.WriteLine(jsonArr[0]);

        // print 2nd json
        Console.WriteLine("This the 2nd json");
        Console.WriteLine(jsonArr[1]);
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: it didn't work well for me. jsonArr has the array of string and then when we do jsonArr[0] that basically gave me the same string as the original one

Comment: @BiswajitMaharana Earlier I asked you the format of your json, you said it is the same you mentioned in question. To simulate your case, I copied that json as it is and pasted in a text file. Then in my console application I read the text file, split the string using the custom delimiter. After that `jsonArr[0]` contains the first json and `jsonArr[1]` contains the 2nd json in the file. Are you using the same json format as the one you posted in question?

Comment: I have provided one sample request payload for the issue, in the actual scenario the payload has some additional attributes in it, does your answer is specific to the exact same payload? Because when I tested it with the actual payload it didn't work well

Comment: @BiswajitMaharana The attributes don't affect but the section where a json ends and other begins in the file is important. You can share how you append your json into a file, then I can know what to expect. If you could have shared since the beginning on the actual format not the sample format, that could have saved time.

Comment: I didn't add the actual format because of some security concern but have updated the question with the exact same payload that I expect in the file. Also as I mentioned I'll always get two JSON strings in the file with the attributes I've mentioned

Comment: @BiswajitMaharana I updated my answer to include another method to extract json strings from file. Hopefully it will work because its tracks the opening and closing of json string. Note earlier: I didn't mean the actual content but the format because I assumed since the delimiter didn't work for your actual content then the delimiter in sample json does not exist in actual json.

Comment: I did try your new solution and still couldn't get what I wanted. it still has the entire string json inside the variable when I call Console.WriteLine

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little wacky, but I'm taking your string as is and assuming you cannot change it. I'm going to convert it into a json array, to do this we need to wrap in brackets, but also add commas after each outer closing curly braces. This code snippet does it for me.

```
Stack<char> myStack = new Stack<char>();
string s = "";

//Find each outside curly brace and add a comma on the closing brace
foreach(char c in jsonString){
    if(c == '{'){
        myStack.Push(c);
    }
    if(c == '}'){
        myStack.Pop();
        if(myStack.Count == 0){
            //Closing curly, add a comma after
            s += c; 
            s += ',';
            continue;
        }
    }
    s += c;
}

//Wrap in brackets to turn into array
s = s.Insert(0, "[");
s += "]";

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
{
    AllowTrailingCommas = true
};

var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<object[]>(s, options);
Console.WriteLine(obj[0].ToString());
Console.WriteLine(obj[1].ToString());
```

Comment: Thinking more, you could just use an int instead of a stack since its only used to count. Start at 0 and add/sub 1 to it. Same logic

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 2 jsons in one file, I would try somethig like this

```
    var i = 0;
    var countStart = false;
    for (i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        if (text[i] == '}') countStart = true;
        else if (countStart)
        {
            if (text[i] == ',' || text[i] == ']') countStart = false;
            else if (text[i] == '{')  break; 
        }
    }

     var json1 = text.Substring(0, i - 1);
     var json2 = text.Substring(i);
```

or it is better to convert it to a json array

```
    text = "[" + text.Substring(0, i - 1) + ",\n" + text.Substring(i) + "]";
    var jsonArray=JArray.Parse(text);
    string version1 = jsonArray[0]["abc"]["Version"].ToString(); // "1.0"
```

if you have more than 2 jsons, this algorithm could be adjusted very easily too.

```
    var countStart = false;
    var indexList = new List<int> { 0 };
    for (var i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        if (text[i] == '}') countStart = true;
        else if (countStart)
        {
            if (text[i] == ',' || text[i] == ']') countStart = false;
            else if (text[i] == '{') { indexList.Add(i); countStart = false; }
        }
    }

    var json = "[";
    for (var i = 0; i < indexList.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i == indexList.Count - 1)
            json += text.Substring(indexList[i]);
        else
            json += text.Substring(indexList[i], indexList[i + 1] - indexList[i]) + ",";
    }

    json += "]";
    var jsonArray = JArray.Parse(json);
```